# Control over custom post types on a specific page

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm looking for an option to show a specific Custom post type on a specific page. In a category there are 10 posts but on the homepage I just want to show for example 3 specific post types of that category. What is the best way to have control over this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This way you can make a private listing

```
function posts_kind($query){

// page id 4173 show

if(is_page('4173')){

// category id 1 show  

$query->set('cat', 1);

return $query;
}

}

add_action('pre_get_posts','posts_kind');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution for a specific template.